# how to combine vertical and side-by-side <div> layout

Tags: html, css, button, layout

I am trying to build a layout of buttons. I have worked at it for a while now, but I doubt my code would be helpful in understanding my problem. I have included the specs of the buttons on the image below. If you guys could show me how to make this layout it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Start with creating container and appropriate divs inside.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

then you have to position them and set particular width.

```
body, html { height: 100%;  }
.container { height: 100%; }
.container > div { float: left; }
.center { height: 100%; width: 33%; }
.blue { background: blue; width: 33%; min-height: 100%; }
.red { background: red; height: 50% }
.yellow { background: yellow; height: 50% } 
.green { background: green; width: 33%; height: 100% }
```

you can alternativly use flex box to get rid of `float: left`

```
.container { height: 100%; display: flex; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eLq0770h/

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to make three DIV's side by side to make the three columns of your design. (the blue column, the red-and-yellow collumn and the green collumn)

You can then use two more DIV's to split the middle column in to two rows.

Your code would then be structured as follows

```
<div id="site">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        CONTENT
    </div>
    <div id="middlecolumn">
        <div id="middletop">
            CONTENT
        </div>
        <div id="middlebottom">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">
        CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then use CSS to set the widths and heights of these DIV's.
I don't know if this is the right way to do this, but this is how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks great. Here's how I would approach the project http://codepen.io/dfrierson2/pen/RNoWZe.

First I set the wrapper to 100% width then i centered the container with margin: 0 auto; I add a width to the container of 600px and set the height to auto and gave it a css selector class of overflow: hidden so that the container will expand with the content of the divs. I would use Bootstrap as a frame work because it is a responsive frame work with great starter code.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template 
It also has great pre style navs and buttons http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
      <style>
      .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }

      .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 600px;
        height: auto;
        background: yellow;
      }
      .col-md-4 {
        border: 1px solid green;
        float: left;
        width: 198px;
        height: 700px;
      }

      .blue {
        background: blue;
      }

      .red {
        background: red;
        height: 350px;
      }

      .green {
        background: green;

      }

      .one {
         border: 1px solid black;
         height: 350px;
      }

      .two {
         border: 1px solid black;
         height: 350px;
      }

      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 blue">33%</div>
              <div class="col-md-4 red">33%</div>
              <div class="col-md-4 green">
                <div class="col-md-6 one">50%</div>
                <div class="col-md-6 two">50%</div>
              </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```